# Visible Interference of Two Lasers

Tags: laser

If 2 Lasers collide in the air, could they interfere with one another?
Given 2 lasers with a max reach of 10 meters (beyond 10 meters they´re not visible with human eyes)
If those two lasers meet at the exact same point at 11 meters of reach, would it be possible that those lasers create a point visible for human eyes?
So this "point of interference" appears to be hovering?
A smokey or foggy environment could help.

Would it be possible? If yes, what laser should I use, (what wave length)?

[image]

Comment: Partly yes. Still, i don't know what Lasers / Wave-length to use.

Comment: I probably have to weaken the laser in its reach and strength. How do I do that?

Comment: Sorry Steve, but there's a lack of a lot of background for your question. Although Vadim's answer is technically correct, I'm not sure it really satisfies what you are looking for. You seem to be looking for a visual "installation" of some kind. However terms like "max reach of 10m" are not real and your interpretation of interference is just of "combination" which is different from real physical interference. The cross point will be slightly brighter, yes, but the rest of the premises do not culminate into an accurate picture of "crossing beams and human visualization"

Comment: if you want a single, small volume to be visible, you are better off focusing the laser down. Starting with a large low power beam and focusing it gives the appearance of a single small line. However, doing that to be seen only around 10m in distance is practically impossible, I won't go in details.

Comment: even better, hanging a transparent foil 10m away and you will be able to project onto the foil and there will be a much brighter spot where the foil is. Even for daytime, you can create hovering pictures with that method.